# Converter xlsx em xls usando Python e Libreoffice Calc

Tags: python, libreoffice

Boa Noite a todos, tenho um arquivo no formato xlsx, preciso convertê-lo para xls format 56 (Excel 97-2003). Estou utilizando Python e consegui a conversão usando o win32.Dispatch com o ('Excel.Applicaton') porém, preciso que a mesma conversão seja realizada pelo Libreoffice Calc. vou deixar aqui o script que consegui usando o Excel.

```
import win32com.client as win32

xlsx_file = r"D:\xlsx_file.xlsx"

xls_file = r"D:\xls_file.xls"

xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')  # create Excel object

xlApp.Visible = True  # hide Excel window

xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True  # don't update Excel window (no window flashes)

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True  # do not display alerts like updating links

wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsx_file, ReadOnly=True)

wb.SaveAs(Filename=xls_file, FileFormat=56)  # save file as xlsb file format

wb.Close(False)  # closes Excel workbook without saving

xlApp.Quit()  # kill Excel process
```

Preciso que o script seja realizado atraves do Libreoffice Calc no lugar do Excel

Comment: Salve, meu caro. O Stack Overflow não é um site de encomenda de código, e sim de difusão de conhecimento para solução de problemas. Este não é o local para pedir a alguém para transpilar seu código VBA para a linguagem de script do LibreOffice, e sim para buscar ajuda com eventuais bugs ao fazer, você mesmo, seu código na linguagem de script de destino.

Answer (score 0):

Se o problema é a conversão das planilhas de `xlsx` para `xls`. Você pode usar a biblioteca `pandas` para isso.

#### Para ler um arquivo tipo `xlsx`, use o método [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("arquivo.xlsx")
```

**Nota 1**: O comando acima somente trará a primeira *sheet* do arquivo.

**Nota 2**: Esta questão será tratada mais abaixo

#### Para salvar um dataframe como arquivo xls (ou xlsx) use o método [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

```
df.to_excel('output.xls')
```

**Nota 3:** O que define se o arquivo salvo será `xls` ou `xlsx` é a extensão que você coloca no mesmo. Simples assim.

Antes de irmos para a solução, é importante ressaltar que existem vários tipos de *engine* que podem ser usados:

- “xlrd” suporta .xls.
- “openpyxl” suporta novos (e velhos) formatos do Excel.
- “odf” suporta OpenDocument (.odf, .ods, .odt).
- “pyxlsb” suporta arquivos Binário Excel.

Para instalar basta usar o `pip` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Finalmente vamos à solução.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("entrada.xlsx", sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xls', engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    for s, d in df.items():
        d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s)
```

**Nota 4**: Ao passar `sheet_name=None` como parâmetro no método, o mesmo retornará um dicionário tendo o nome das planilhas como chaves e os dados nos valores.

**Nota 5**: Provavelmente você não irá querer salvar o índices. Para tal, use o parâmetro `index=False`

Finalmente, perceba que você pode usar um engine para ler e outro para salvar. Sendo assim, você poderá ler de `xlsx` e salvar direto para `ods`.

Comment: Olá Paulo, primeiro agradecer demais pela ajuda e dizer que sua sugestão funcionou aqui, porém, para meu caso, com uma modificação. Tive que alterar a engine para 'auto' e instalar o módulo xlwt. Preciso de outra ajuda, na criação do arquivo xls aparece uma linha superior com nomes das colunas Unnamed: 0... Como faço para remover essa coluna no momento da criação do arquivo xls?

Comment: Consegui Paulo, header=False. Muito obrigado meu amigo, fica com Deus!!!

Comment: Caso ache pertinente, favor marcar a resposta como sendo solução do problema. Veja [esse](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas) post.